# Previous day of current_date() in Hue hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, hue

I'm trying to write a query to return records from a column called "businessdate" (which is in the YYYY-MM-DD format, and it is a string data type), using the previous days "businessdate" records and am stuck. I've tried different things, and I get error messages ranging from argument or matching method, etc. It's probably simple, and I feel dumb. Please help!

Query;

```
Select businessdate from dbname
Where businessdate = current_date - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use date_sub function to subtract one day from current_date:

```
select businessdate 
  from dbname.tablename
 where businessdate = date_sub(current_date,1)
```